# How do similar looking carps, but belonging to different species, differ from each other?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology, species

There are some carps which differ in colour, or has some easily noticeable morphological differences. But apart from that, most of the carps look "almost" the same. How does one differentiate one species from another?
Citing behavioral differences, differences in morphological characteristics (maybe subtle) and the likes which addresses this problem would be helpful. The characteristics with broader scope would be better.

Comment: This might actually be a more complicated question. The [phylogeny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprinidae#Systematics) for carps and other members of the *Cyprinidae* family have not been well resolved. Also, "Carp" belong to numerous genera including *Carassius, Cirrhinus,  Ctenopharyngodon, Cyprinus, Hypophthalmichthy, Mylopharyngodon*, etc. so they're not all actually related (below the family level). I would assume you could find a fairly easy way to differentiate these genera from each other. But...Given all this, are you seeking to differentiate *all* carp or just *Cyprinus* species?

Comment: I framed this question mainly keeping Cyprinus species in mind.

Comment: There isn't actually. Every species of Cyprinidae has its own distinct characters and sometimes for the ones that are too similar, like Labeo rohita, Labeo bata and Mrigel one can only distinguish them after regular examination. There's no set rules/guidelines but ones you develop an eye you know what ways they are different. Yet knowing the fin formula can help. But learning them all for so many species and remembering them is absolutely beyond human abilities.

Comment: If you are interested in some specific species. I think this can be answered.

Comment: Let's consider a school of fresh water carps which is readily available. I would like to know of some specific characteristics which are more effective than others when it comes to distinguishing between them i.e. if most of them can be told apart using a trait then it is significant. Developing an eye is just an observation, deducing inferences and standardizing them in a way, so that they can be used to understand subtleties, is what science should be all about.

Comment: Do you have a region of interest? As above commenters have mentioned, Cyprinid ID's are really hard. My general algorithm for fish ID typically involves a gestalt feel for family, and, depending on my familiarity with local members of the group, either referencing my internal catalog of species present (incorporating local abundance) or finding a field guide or key. But identifying species from afar? That's not going to be easy, esp. Not without some baseline familiarity with morphology and behavior.

Comment: I've edited the question.